# регулярка для парсинга строки

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Приветствую, не могу написать регулярку что бы разбить строку на нужные данные.
Имеется список скинов:

```
★ Falchion Knife | Boreal Forest (Factory New)
Souvenir FAMAS | Teardown (Battle-Scarred)
★ StatTrak™ Flip Knife | Lore (Field-Tested)
★ Bayonet | Autotronic (Battle-Scarred)
AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)
★ Karambit | Bright Water (Battle-Scarred)
StatTrak™ Negev | Man-o'-war (Minimal Wear)
★ M9 Bayonet | Marble Fade (Minimal Wear)
★ StatTrak™ Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler (Minimal Wear)
Tec-9 | Nuclear Threat (Factory New)
Souvenir Tec-9 | Nuclear Threat (Minimal Wear)
★ StatTrak™ Karambit 
★ StatTrak™ Gut Knife 
★ Huntsman Knife
```

**Доп. информация:**
★ - означает, что это нож
StatTrak™ - скин имеет счетчик выстрелов
Souvenir - сувенирный скин
(Minimal Wear) - качество скина
AK-47 | Redline - имя скина

Нужно с помощью регулярного выражения вывести данные такое как:
1. сувенирный ли скин
2. нож ли это
3. имеет ли счетчик
4. имя скина
5. если имеется, то качество

Приложил разъяснительные материалы: https://jsfiddle.net/zn6Lk233/3/

Comment: Для Вашей задачи не нужно использовать регулярные выражения. На JSFiddle присутствует HTML-разметка, Вам ее нужно распарсить? Или строки являются текстом?

Comment: @XelaNimed текстом, я занес все примеры, которые должны подходить под одно и то же регулярное выражение, в массив. HTML что бы лучше понять какая часть строки чем называется.

Comment: Я не уверен, что одна регулярка даст ответ сразу на 5 вопросов. Для каждого сделать регулярку - тогда возможно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не обязательно использовать именно регулярные выражения, можете сделать следующим образом:

```js
var weapons = [
  '★ Falchion Knife | Boreal Forest (Factory New)',
  'Souvenir FAMAS | Teardown (Battle-Scarred)',
  '★ StatTrak™ Flip Knife | Lore (Field-Tested)',
  '★ Bayonet | Autotronic (Battle-Scarred)',
  'AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)',
  '★ Karambit | Bright Water (Battle-Scarred)',
  'StatTrak™ Negev | Man-o\'-war (Minimal Wear)',
  '★ M9 Bayonet | Marble Fade (Minimal Wear)',
  '★ StatTrak™ Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler (Minimal Wear)',
  'Tec-9 | Nuclear Threat (Factory New)',
  'Souvenir Tec-9 | Nuclear Threat (Minimal Wear)',
  '★ StatTrak™ Karambit',
  '★ StatTrak™ Gut Knife',
  '★ Huntsman Knife'
];
var weaponString = weapons.join("\n");

function weaponParser(weapons) {
  this.weapons = weapons;
}

weaponParser.prototype.getProperties = function() {
  return [{
    name: "означает, что это нож",
    regex: /★/,
    prop: "isKnife",
    saveRegexValue: false
  }, {
    name: "скин имеет счетчик выстрелов",
    regex: /StatTrak™/,
    prop: "isShoot",
    saveRegexValue: false
  }, {
    name: "сувенирный скин",
    regex: /Souvenir/,
    prop: "isSouvenir",
    saveRegexValue: false
  }, {
    name: "качество скина",
    regex: /\(.*\)/,
    prop: "quality",
    saveRegexValue: true
  }];
}

weaponParser.prototype.parse = function() {
  var lines = this.weapons.split("\n");
  var items = this.getProperties();
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    var weapon = {};
    for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
      var property = items[j];
      if (property.saveRegexValue)
        weapon[property.prop] = property.regex.exec(line);
      else
        weapon[property.prop] = property.regex.test(line);
      if (weapon[property.prop])
        line = line.replace(property.regex, '');
    }
    weapon.name = line;
    result.push(weapon);
  }
  return result;
}

var parser = new weaponParser(weaponString);
var result = parser.parse();
console.log(result);
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/bhhq4s0e/1/).

Пример с использованием регулярного выражения.

```js
var weapons = [
  '★ Falchion Knife | Boreal Forest (Factory New)',
  '★ Souvenir FAMAS | Teardown (Battle-Scarred)',
  '★ StatTrak™ Flip Knife | Lore (Field-Tested)',
  '★ Bayonet | Autotronic (Battle-Scarred)',
  'AK-47 | Redline (Field-Tested)',
  '★ Karambit | Bright Water (Battle-Scarred)',
  'StatTrak™ Negev | Man-o\'-war (Minimal Wear)',
  '★ M9 Bayonet | Marble Fade (Minimal Wear)',
  '★ StatTrak™ Flip Knife | Gamma Doppler (Minimal Wear)',
  'Tec-9 | Nuclear Threat (Factory New)',
  'Souvenir Tec-9 | Nuclear Threat (Minimal Wear)',
  '★ StatTrak™ Karambit',
  '★ StatTrak™ Gut Knife',
  '★ Huntsman Knife'
];
var weaponString = weapons.join("\n");


function weaponParserRegex(weapons) {
  this.weapons = weapons;
}
weaponParserRegex.prototype.parse = function() {
  var lines = this.weapons.split("\n");
  var regex = /(★)?\s*(StatTrak™)?\s*(Souvenir)?\s*(.*)\s*(\(.*\))*/;
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
    var line = lines[i];
    line.replace(regex, function(text, knife, starTrack, souvenir, name, quality) {
      result.push({
        knife: !!knife,
        starTrack: !!starTrack,
        souvenir: !!souvenir,
        name: name,
        quality: quality,
        text: text
      })
    })
  }
  return result;
}

var parser = new weaponParserRegex(weaponString);
var result = parser.parse();
console.log(result);
```

Пример на [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/41jw71fo/).

Comment: оба Ваших примера используют регулярные выражения. Что Вы имели ввиду, когда писали "Если не обязательно использовать именно регулярные выражения"?

Comment: Извините, может не верно выразился. Насколько я понял, было необходимо получить значения с помощью *одного* регулярного выражения. В первом случае я использую 4 регулярных выражения, а не одно. А во втором случае использую только одно регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 1):

Либо можно так:

```
// skinList is element ID of textarea
var lines = $("#skinsList").val().split("\n"),
    skins = [];

lines.forEach(function(item){

  var skin = {
    isSouvenir : false,
    isKnife : false,
    hasCounter : false,
    counterName : null,
    quality : null,
    name : null
  },
  line = item;

  var starPos = line.indexOf("★");
  if(starPos != -1){
      skin.isKnife = true;
      line = line.substr(starPos + 2);
  }

  var souvenirPos = line.indexOf("Souvenir");
  if(souvenirPos != -1){
      skin.isSouvenir = true;
      line = line.substr(souvenirPos + "Souvenir".length + 1);
  }

  var bracePos = line.indexOf("(");
  if(bracePos != -1){
      skin.quality = line.substring(bracePos + 1, line.indexOf(")"));
      line = line.substring(0, bracePos - 1);
  }

  if(line.indexOf("™ ") != -1){
      var tmp = line.split("™ ");
      skin.counterName = tmp[0];
      skin.hasCounter = true;
      line = tmp[1];
  }

  skin.name = line;

  skins.push(skin);
});
```

Пример разбора без использования регулярных выражений [на JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/XelaNimed/42jwn8sa/)